# SoapFault - Request Entity is Too Large

Tags: http, nginx, soap, laravel-5, soap-client

I am trying to send a Soap request with file content. If I send small file ~25KB is it file but if I try to send bigger file ~256KB its says

> SoapFault - Request Entity is Too Large

```
Example request: 

    Array
    (
        [DTOPostTransaction] => Array
            (
                [AmountFC] => 40.00
                [AmountLLC] => 4440.00
                [BeneAccType] => 
                [BeneAccountNo] => 324
                [CustomerDocs] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [DocCategory] => 5
                                [DocType] => 12
                                [DocNo] => 7777
                                [IssuedBy] => Gov
                                [IssueDate] => 2017-06-01
                                [ExpiryDate] => 2017-07-31
                                [FileName] => doc_fJLUCKU4YN8YI2cyvvgf.png
                                [FileContent] => �PNG


    IHDR0w�Dq&  pHYs��
    OiCCPPhotoshop ICC profilexڝSgTS�=���BK���KoR RB���&*!  J�!��Q�EEȠ�����Q,�
    ��!���������{�kּ������>�����H3Q5��B�������.@�
    $p�d!s�#�~<<+"��x��M��0���B�\���t�8K�@z�B�@F���&S�`�cb�P-`'������{[�!�� e�Dh;��V�EX0fK�9�-0IWfH�����0Q��){`�##x��F�W<�+��*x��<�$9E�[-qWW.(�I+6aa�@.�y�2�4���������x����6��_-��"bb���ϫp@�t~��,/��;�m��%�h^�u��f�@����W�p�~<�5�j>{�-�]c�K'Xt����o��(�h���w��?�G�%�fI�q^D$.Tʳ?�D��*�A��,�����`6�B$��BB
    d�r`)��B(�Ͱ*`/�@4�Qh��p.�U�=p�a��(�� A�a!ڈb�X#����!�H�$ ɈQ"K�5H1R�T UH�=r9�\F��;�2����G1���Q=��C��7�F��dt1�����r�=�6��Ыhڏ>C�0��3�l0.��B�8,  �c˱"����V����cϱw�E� 6wB aAHXLXN�H� $4�  7   �Q�'"��K�&���b21�XH,#��/{�C�7$�C2'��I��T��F�nR#�,��4H#���dk�9�, +ȅ����3��!�[
    �b@q��S�(R�jJ��4�e�2AU��Rݨ�T5�ZB���R�Q��4u�9̓IK�����hh�i��t�ݕN��W���G���w
    ))))

            //soap request 
            $mode = array(
                'soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_1', 
                'trace' => 1,
                'execptions' => 1,
                'use' => 'SOAP_LITERAL'
            );

            // initialize soap client
            $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $mode);

            //set location 
            $client->__setLocation($location);

            $post = $client->__soapCall('PostTransaction', array($request));
```

I am using nginx server and I have already updated client_max_body_size and post_max_size but no success!

Please help. Thank you in advance ...